# Evento add div javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Tenho um código onde existe um formulário e o usuário poderá escolher a quantidade de linhas clicando em botões que estão na frente do input, existe um botao '+' para adicionar novo um input e '-' para remover o input atual.

Segue o código:

```
 <div class="posicao-radioButton botoes">
   <div class="input">
     <input type="radio" disabled name="idade"><input type="text" 
      name="quest1"><a href=""><img class="img-add" title="Adicionar uma 
      linha" src="img/add.png"></a><a href=""><img class="img-remove" 
      title="Remover Linha" src="img/remove.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

estes botoes estão conectados com eventos do jquery que irá adicionar uma linha toda vez que + for clicado.

```
$(function(){
    $(".img-add").click(function(e){
       event.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");
        var parente = $(this).closest(".input");
        parente.clone().appendTo( ".botoes" );
    })
})
```

porém este código está funcionando apenas parcialmente, já que o evento funciona apenas para o primeiro botão que é criado com a página e não com os outros.
Alguém sabe o que está faltando para funcionar o evento em todos os botões que forem criados?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você adiciona um novo elemento (o `.input`) você deve adicionar o evento de `click` nessa nova `div`.

Extrai a função e reutiliza ela para as div's que forem adicionadas.

```
$(function(){
    let onClick = function(e){
       event.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");
        var parente = $(this).closest(".input");
        var cloneParente = parente.clone().click(onClick);
        cloneParente.appendTo( ".botoes" );
    };

    $(".img-add").click(onClick);
})
```

Comment: Deu certo!! Obrigado ;D

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do André está correta, porém existe uma forma que requer menos esforço.

Apenas troque a função `click` pela função `on`, da seguinte forma:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.input").on("click", "a", function(e) { // eis o pulo do gato
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");
        let parente = $(this).closest(".input");
        parente.clone().appendTo(".botoes");
    });
}
```

Explicação: seu código atual associa um evento somente à imagem que existe no momento em que o código é executado. Já o código acima associa o evento `click` a todos os elementos `a` que forem filhos da `div` de classe `input`, agora **e no futuro**.

[Este é o link para a documentação do on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). O trecho relevante é o seguinte:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Em português, tradução minha, com ênfase nas partes importantes:

> Eventos delegados tem a vantagem de poder processar eventos de **elementos descendentes** (filhos) que forem **adicionados mais tarde** ao documento (a página). Utilizando `on` em um elemento que garantidamente está presente na hora que o `handler` é associado, **você evita a necessidade de ficar associando o mesmo evento a cada novo elemento adicionado**.

Comment: Eu achava que click e on.("click") eram a mesma coisa bom saber que não é, mas mesmo assim ele continou com o mesmo problema de ouvir só o primeiro elemento. Mas obrigado mesmo assim ;D